# Not most people like him

Tags: grammar, usage

*Question 1:*

> **Not most people like him.**
>
> **Not most of them are good looking.**

As far as I know, before the words like "many", "a lot", "some" and "every", we can use the word "not" for not causing any ambiguity depending on what we want to mean. I think we can use it before "most" too. Am I right? Are these two sentences above correct?

*Question 2:*

Can I also say these:

> **Not most of the time I play video games.**
>
> **I play video games not most of the time.**

I think the sentences in question 1 are correct but I feel like these two here are wrong. I think I have to say "I don't play video games most of the time" even if I play video games quite often (quite often but not most of the time), am I right?

*EDIT:* In the first question, I mean "Not most people do like him". What In t I mean by saying it is not "Most people do not like him.". I mean, there can be many people who like him, but not most people like him. For example, 50% of people might like him and that's a lot, but that's not most people. If I say "Most people don't like him" for describing this situation, it is wrong because %50 doesn't count as most people. But, John Lawler said that it was wrong to say "Not most people...". So, I don't know what to do

Comment: _Not many/much/all/every/a lot_ are idiomatic negative quantifiers. They don't inflect for comparative and superlative, because negative terms almost always have different grammar rules from ordinary terms. So that means you're wrong -- *_not most_ does not occur as a quantifier (i.e, at the beginning or a noun phrase). The sequence _not_ and _most_ can occur in a verb phrase if _most_ occurs at the beginning of a complement phrase after a negative auxiliary, as in _The political infighting was not most of it; the accounting software itself caused the problem._

Comment: Your first sentence is ambiguous **Not most people like him.** Do you mean:  1) Most people **do not like** him.  or  2) Most people are **not similar** to him.

Comment: @Peter I mean **"Not most people do like him"** What I mean by saying it is not **"Most people do not like him.".** I mean, there can be many people who like him, but not most people like him. For example, 50% of people might like him and that's a lot, but that's not most people. If I say **"Most people don't like him"** for describing this situation, it is wrong because %50 doesn't count as most people. But, John Lawler said that it was wrong to say **"Not most people..."**. So, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @DereMemo **Not most people** = *less than most* = **some people**, Most natives would say "***Some people do not like him.***" They would not use your "***not most people***" construction.

Comment: @Peter Do you agree with that **"Not most people"** is grammatically wrong?

Comment: @DereMemo As a stand alone phrase "***Not most people***" can be used to refute "***Most people*** think you're dumb!", "***Not most people***, not even some people, maybe a few think I'm dumb...".  It is not grammatically wrong, but it can be misused and awkward.

Comment: @Peter Thanks. So, are the sentences in the OP where it is not used as a stand alone phrase wrong in any case?

Comment: @DereMemo Grammatically no, but semantically awkward.